# Can you answer a call with AirPods faster than EarPods?

Tags: iphone, airpods

I am considering to purchase the Apple Airpods. Currently I use Apple Earpods. My only consideration in this purchase is: **how fast can I answer a call and start using it**.

Could someone who has both please measure the time it take to:

CONTESTANT A

- Remove AirPods from a purse/bag
- Open case
- Insert pods to ear
- Switch over from talking with phone to talking with pods

CONTESTANT B

- Remove EarPods from bag
- Unwrap earphones (wrapped using the power-chord crossover style)
- Insert phones to ear
- Plug phones into phone

This is a serious question. I do not like all these new products with a million new features but the one important thing adds a few seconds to each use. So I need to know if the AirPods are a step forward or a step backward.

Comment: This is a fact-based question about benchmarking Apple products. Why the hate?

Comment: Can't you purchase them yourself and try the experiment?  If you don't like them you can return them to Apple for your money back or ebay them.

Comment: There are way too many factors involved in this in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

AirPods are much quicker, as you don't have to spend 5 minutes untangling them. No matter how you wrap them, [it's going to happen.](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/seriouslyscience/2014/06/18/scientific-explanation-earphones-always-tangled/#.WTlwpmjyuUk)
Also, switching is automatic, so no need to worry there.